# MSI prevent registry key repair

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I created an MSI setup via Visual Studio 2008 for my application, and added a registry key to windows\run for automatic startup, but also implemented a function in my application to disable automatic startup. However, when the application is restarted, the key is automatically repaired.

How to prevent MSI from repairing the key??

Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [MSI Installer start auto-repair when service starts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596431/msi-installer-start-auto-repair-when-service-starts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registry key is repaired because it was installed by your package and Windows Installer knows that it should be present. Some possible solutions are:

1. Move the entry in a separate component which doesn't have a Component ID. This way the component is not registered with Windows Installer.
2. Use a custom action to create the registry entry during install.

Comment: thanks, but I don't know how to do either. Could you care to explain? I don't know how to choose the component ID of the entry, not how to create a custom action for that, since visual studio doesn't offer me any such thing in custom actions...

Comment: You can edit the components with Orca or with a more powerful tool. Visual Studio is very limited when it comes to creating installers. A custom action can use custom code. For example you can create an EXE which handles the registry entries. After creating the EXE you can add it as a custom action in your setup project.